# SBS 2011 Premium Add-on Licencing After migration to Windows 2012 Standard

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

We are currently running an **SBS 2011 Standard Server**(A). We have **Premium Add-on Licence** and have installed **SQL server** on the same SBS 2011 Server. We have installed **Windows 2008 R2 Standard** on another server(B).

We plan to buy a new server with **Windows Server 2012 Standard**. This will be the PDC in the future. SBS2011 will be un-installed.

Can I continue to use the Windows 2008 R2 Server from the Premium Add-on on server (B) even when the SBS 2011 domain server is un-installed and re-purposed? Can I install the Premium Add-on's SQL Server for Small Business 2008 on the **Windows 2008 R2 Server(B)**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.dell.com/downloads/us/bsd/bsd/SBS_Premium_Add-on%20Datasheet_Final.pdf :

**Q.** Are there any restrictions for the server technologies included in the Windows Small Business Server 2011 Premium Add-on?

**A.** There are no restrictions at all. You get full access to all SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard technologies. **To ensure full access, the installation process includes a domain check to verify that SBS 2011 Standard or Essentials is present.**

Comment: Don't see why this was downvoted.  Seems to be a pretty definitive answer.